# Wordpress - How can I add a textarea and a button into New Post screen?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to write a bot for my wordpress site. But I couldn't find the answer of that question. How can I add a textarea and a button to my wordpress new post page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit a file in your theme called index.php. Anywhere before or after the loop (so that you don't create a new textbox and button every time). Just use

```
<textarea>
    your text here.
</textarea>
<button>My Button</button>
```

Comment: Editing my index page doesn't effect to my home page? Am I wrong?

Comment: By default, your home page uses index.php though you can change this in your theme settings